# How i remove authentication system from a controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-8

***I want to remove authentication system from a controller.***

This is my controller code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\rfq;
use App\Models\customer_rfq;

class ShowRfqController extends Controller
{
    public function inforfq($name)
    {
        $rfq = rfq::find($name);
        return view('frontend.sellershowrfq',compact('rfq'));
    }

    public function customer_inforfq($name)
    {
        $customer_rfq = customer_rfq::find($name);
        return view('frontend.customershowrfq',compact('customer_rfq'));
    }
}
```

**This is my models code.**

This is code of customer_rfq model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class customer_rfq extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'customer_rfq';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'Price',
        'MobileNo',
        'quantity',
        'image',
    ];
}
```

This is code of rfq model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App;

class rfq extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'rfq';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'Price',
        'MobileNo',
        'quantity',
        'image'
    ];
}
```

**This is my views code.**

This is my customerrfqshow.blade.php view code.

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="mb-4 pt-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bg-white shadow-sm rounded p-3">
                <div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 35px;" class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="sticky-top z-3 row gutters-10">
                            <div class="col order-1 order-md-2">
                                <div class="aiz-carousel product-gallery" data-nav-for='.product-gallery-thumb' data-fade='true' data-auto-height='true'>
                                    <div class="carousel-box img-zoom rounded">
                                        <img class="img-fluid lazyload" src="{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}" data-src="{{ uploaded_asset($customer_rfq->image) }}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}';" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h2 style="text-transform: capitalize;">
                            <b> {{ $customer_rfq->name }} </b>
                        </h2>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;1">{{ translate('Approx Price')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;" name="price">
                                <b> Rs. {{ $customer_rfq->Price }}.00/- </b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;">{{ translate('Quantity')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;" name="quantity">
                                <b>{{ $customer_rfq->quantity }}</b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;1">{{ translate('Total Price')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;">
                                <b>Rs. {{ $customer_rfq->quantity*$customer_rfq->Price }}.00/-</b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row no-gutters mt-4">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="opacity-50 my-2">{{ translate('Share')}}:</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <div class="aiz-share"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

This is my sellershoerfq.blade.php view code.

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="mb-4 pt-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bg-white shadow-sm rounded p-3">
                <div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 35px;" class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="sticky-top z-3 row gutters-10">
                            <div class="col order-1 order-md-2">
                                <div class="aiz-carousel product-gallery" data-nav-for='.product-gallery-thumb' data-fade='true' data-auto-height='true'>
                                    <div class="carousel-box img-zoom rounded">
                                        <img class="img-fluid lazyload" src="{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}" data-src="{{ uploaded_asset($rfq->image) }}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{ static_asset('assets/img/placeholder.jpg') }}';" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h2 style="text-transform: capitalize;">
                            <b> {{ $rfq->name }} </b>
                        </h2>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;">{{ translate('Approx Price')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;" name="price">
                                <b> Rs. {{ $rfq->Price }}.00/- </b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;">{{ translate('Quantity')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;" name="quantity">
                                <b>{{ $rfq->quantity }}</b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="opacity-50 my-2" style="font-size: 15px;">{{ translate('Total Price')}}:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h2 style="color: red; font-style:;">
                                <b>Rs. {{ $rfq->quantity*$rfq->Price }}.00/-</b>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row no-gutters mt-4">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="opacity-50 my-2">{{ translate('Share')}}:</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <div class="aiz-share"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

When i run `127.0.0.1:8080/inforfq/1` This will redirect me to the login page.

How i remove the authentication system from `127.0.0.1:8080/inforfq/1`.

Comment: Lots of code ... what is your "routes" code?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the web middleware,
check your route file for something like :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']
```

or :

```
Route::get('')->middleware('web');
```

Remove the web middleware or move the route outside of the group

You should also check RouteServiceProvider, the middleware could be defined here, cf :

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

if that the case like here :

```
Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

change to :

```
Route::namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

be aware that web middleware will not be included by default now, so you should add a route group with that middleware, for all authenticated routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
// all your previously authenticated routes goes here
});
// everything else is not authenticated by web middlware
```

if you have a lot of those routes, it's better to create a routes/public.php and add that to your provider :

```
Route::namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/public.php'));
```

that way you don't have to remove web middleware from routes/web.php and it's cleaner and avoid mistakes, because it's easy to forget that web.php don't have web middleware anymore